# Create SQL trigger if data exists in table

Tags: sql, triggers

I am new to SQL.

What is the best way to create a TXT file, if a table has records > 0?

The code already exists to remove or add records to this table.

I am looking for ways to create a trigger file (with no content in the file) at a specific network folder.

Preferably, I would want this TXT file to be removed at the end of the day, so the process could repeat itself every morning

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to achieve are you trying to monitor which table has data in it?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? (*SQL* is not DBMS, it's query language)

Answer (score 0):

On an after delete Trigger do a select count(*) from table or query one of the system catalog views.  If its zero, then call a stored proc that poops a file onto your share drive.

To move the file you could create a small package or call a powershell or bcp (after enabling xp_cmdshell though), or you could create a CLR function (after enabling CLR).  I guess since the latter two you need to change a server setting, you could just create a package.

Annnd since there is no data you dont actually need to export, you just create a blank file!